# How to combine elements of multiple lists in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am new to Scala. I have three List.

```
List("XX", None,None,None)

List( None,"YY",None,None)

List(None,None,None, "ZZ")
```

I need to merge these list to create a single list which should look like

```
List("XX","YY",None,"ZZ")
```

Is there any way in scala to achieve this result? Thanks

Comment: Does the order matter?   Does the types are always String or None?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lists are `List[AnyRef]`. That's a type that should never appear in ordinary Scala code.

I would suggest representing your data using `List[Option[String]]`:

```
scala> List(List(Some("XX"), None, None, None),
     |      List(None, Some("YY"), None, None),
     |      List(None, None, None, Some("ZZ")))
res2: List[List[Option[String]]] = List(...
```

Now your problem is easy to solve:

```
scala> res2.transpose.map(_.flatten.headOption)
res6: List[Option[String]] = List(Some(XX), Some(YY), None, Some(ZZ))
```

I've assumed here that if there are multiple `Some`s in the same position, you want to take the first one.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you need this?

```
val list: List[List[Option[String]]] = List(
  List(Some("XX"), None, None, None),
  List(None, Some("YY"), None, None),
  List(None, None, None, Some("ZZ"))
)
list.tail.foldLeft(list.head) {
  case (acc, item) => acc.zip(item).map {
    case (Some(x), _) => Some(x)
    case (_, y) => y
  }
}
```

Comment: The fold function can be `{ case (a, x) => (a, x).zipped map { case (y, z) => y orElse z } }` where zipped avoids an intermediate collection.

Answer (score 2):

```
val l1 = List("XX", None, None, None)
val l2 = List(None, "YY", None, None)
val l3 = List(None, None, None, "ZZ")

val listOfList = List(l1, l2, l3) 

// Assuming all lists are of same length.

val lT = listOfList.transpose  // swap column and rows
val result = lT.map{ _.reduce{ (a, b) => 
  if (a.toString == "None") b else a
}}
// List[Serializable] = List(XX, YY, None, ZZ)
```

Comment: Testing for `None` that way is especially stringly (i.e., bad). Bad as in awful.

Comment: @som-snytt point accepted. but starting from given data, its a way to achieve the result. others have made the point that starting place should be List of options. I agree.

Answer (score 2):

For

```
val xs = List(list1,list2,list2)
```

consider

```
xs.flatten.distinct
```